# How to do mapping the type of Queue<string> with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

For example:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public Queue<string> strings{get;set;}
    }
```

In nhibernate, how to mapping the type of Queue ,help me!

Comment: Do you have a database with a type system that supports Queues? I'm not aware of one.

Comment: How do you expect the queue to be persisted in the DB? You'd need to answer that before trying to map it.

Comment: You could look into ICompositeUserType and IUserType interfaces from NHibernate.UserTypes namespace. There are enough examples around. just google

Answer (score 0):

why dont you update and store a list of a DTO which is a combination of the string and the index/order in which it was added to the queue and store this in your database. Your Queue property get reads from this list and then builds up the queue and your set property of the queue updates the list.

Is that a possible workaround for you?